# Javascript closure: dynamically-defined functions, call method from current scope

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a static function that calls a dynamically defined function? I need this because I can't change the static function, and all I know is that it calls the dynamic function. For example:

```
function staticFunc() {
  dynamicFunc();
}

function test() {
  function dynamicFunc() {console.log('yay');}
  staticFunc();
};

test();
```

but it gives me the error `dynamicFunc is not defined`.

I know that if I hardcode `staticFunc` in `test()`, it works. I also noticed that I only get the error when I call `staticFunc`, not when I define it (even though `dynamicFunc` is not defined yet), which makes it seem like `staticFunc` is running inside `test()`'s scope, but evidently not.

Any way to do this? The only way I can think of is to make a global function `funcPtr` that gets assigned to my dynamic function.

Comment: can you pass the "dynamicFunc" to teh "staticFunc" like staticFunc(dynamicFunc);?

Comment: nope, staticFunc is given to me, not defined by me

Answer (score 2):

Closure is you can use variable of parent level scope in child level scope. Here in your case it is reverse you have initialize a function in a child level scope and try to invoke it in parent scope which is not correct.

You may pass current function as parameter and invoke it:

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WZYPq/)

```
function staticFunc(dynamicFunc) {
  dynamicFunc();
}

function test() {
  var dynamicFunc = function() {console.log('yay');}
  staticFunc(dynamicFunc);
};

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dynamicFunc = null;
function test() {
    dynamicFunc = function () {console.log('yay');}
    staticFunc();
};
```

Considering that you can't change anything on your *static* function, the solution changes the declaration of `dynamicFunc` to a var that contains a function.

This can throw an exception if the static function tries to call `dynamicFunc` when its `null`. But you can declare as this:

```
var dynamicFunc = function() {};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX688/).

Comment: thanks you, as I mentioned that was one of the solutions I was considering. I'd like to avoid polluting the global namespace as much as possible, but I guess you can't ask for too much :)

Comment: @woojoo666 I believe that is this case you have no choice =/

Comment: @woojoo666 Overriding the "dynamicFunc" already referenced in the "static" does not pollute the global namespace, as the variable (dynFunc) is already defined globally; you will just overwrite that one.

Comment: I was trying to avoid defining `dynamicFunc` globally in the first place

Comment: wasn't the 'staticFunc' calling the 'dynamicFunc' given that way?? Generally, there should be no need to define such functs globally, question just is which is the scope, the two conceptually share..